# all loud colors and improbable cuts -- what does "cuts" mean in this context?

Tags: comprehension

Example ([Putin Would Eat President Trump for Lunch](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-07-31/putin-would-eat-trump-for-lunch?cmpid=yhoo)):

> One is Yevgeny Chichvarkin, co-founder of the Yevroset chain of mobile phone shops. Like Trump, he is flamboyant and outspoken. Trump sold a line of rather tasteless clothes under his name until Macy's discontinued it earlier this month. Chichvarkin is famous for dressing like a pop star -- all loud colors and improbable **cuts**. Trump hosted "The Apprentice" on NBC; Chichvarkin was one of the five hosts of "Kapital" on Russia's TNT channel, judging   investment pitches from young entrepreneurs. Trump likes to curse, and so does Chichvarkin.

What kind of cuts is the author talking about?

Comment: That makes a good answer. (With or without a reference.)

Comment: @StoneyB, make that an answer.  It is consise and right on target.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan As you wish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "cut" of a garment is its shape, conferred upon it by the shapes into which the fabric is cut by the tailor.

(Note, by the way, that *tailor* is originally French *tailleur*—literally, "cutter".)

An improbable "cut" is one which is so extravagant or outré that it defies tailoring convention.